# Github - Delete a fork that was created from my repo

Tags: git, github

Is it possible for me to delete a fork that was created out of my repo. The repo was forked by someone else and I want to delete the forked repo. I am able to see the fork from my insights tab.

Comment: That's why github has private repos, my friend. Did you put a license file in there? Probably your best bet is to contact them.

Comment: no , we have a build process which is failing due to a forked repo. It's my team mate who has forked it , but just wanted to check if I can delete it myself.

Comment: Then ask your teammate to delete it. You don't own their repository just because it was forked from yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if you're an admin of the fork, you could delete it.

It's then in settings -> options -> section "danger zone"

[image]

Comment: Thanks , should the person who forked the repo has to delete it?

Comment: yes indeed, or transfer ownership so you could delete it